# Show algebraically that $U|0\rangle\otimes |0\rangle+U|1\rangle\otimes|1\rangle=|0\rangle\otimes U^T|0\rangle+|1\rangle\otimes U^T|1\rangle$

Tags: entanglement, mathematics, textbook-and-exercises, bell-basis

Suppose that Alice applies a unitary operator $U$ with real entries to her qubit in an EPR pair $|\beta\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)$. Is this the same as having Bob apply $U^T$ to his half?

I can't quite show algebraically whether the identity

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(U|0\rangle\otimes |0\rangle+U|1\rangle\otimes|1\rangle)=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|0\rangle\otimes U^T|0\rangle+|1\rangle\otimes U^T|1\rangle)$$

is true or not.
I see that I can get from the LHS to the RHS by applying $U^T\otimes U^T$ as $U^T=U^\dagger=U^{-1}$, but I still haven't made progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, application of $U$ to Alice's half of $|\beta\rangle=(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ and appliaction of $U^T$ to Bob's half are equivalent. In fact the identity

$$
(A \otimes I)|\beta\rangle = (I \otimes A^T) |\beta\rangle
$$

is true for any matrix (not necessarily unitary or real). Let

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{00} & a_{01} \\
a_{10} & a_{11}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and compare

$$
(A \otimes I)|\beta\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
a_{00} & 0 & a_{01} & 0 \\
0 & a_{00} & 0 & a_{01} \\
a_{10} & 0 & a_{11} & 0 \\
0 & a_{10} & 0 & a_{11} \\
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix} =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
a_{00} \\ a_{01} \\ a_{10} \\ a_{11}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

with

$$
(I \otimes A^T) |\beta\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{00} & a_{10} & 0 & 0 \\
a_{01} & a_{11} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a_{00} & a_{10} \\
0 & 0 & a_{01} & a_{11}
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix} =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
a_{00} \\ a_{01} \\ a_{10} \\ a_{11}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

A more elegant way to prove the identity uses tensor networks, see example 9 and equation $(46)$ on page 12 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.00006).

Comment: Nice. I didn't think that this could hold more generally - hence I never thought about plugging in a generic matrix.

Comment: I was playing around with this a bit, and bar mistakes I found that the overlap between the two states should be $\text{Tr}(U)^2/2$. What's up with this? It doesn't look right.

Comment: $((I\otimes U^T)|\beta\rangle)^\dagger (U\otimes I)|\beta\rangle = \langle\beta|U\otimes \overline{U}|\beta\rangle = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{ij}\langle i|\langle i|U\otimes \overline{U}|j\rangle|j \rangle = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{ij} u_{ij} \overline{u_{ij}} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{ij} u_{ij}u_{ji}^\dagger = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}(UU^\dagger) = 1$

Comment: Right, so this is the best way to prove this for unitary matrices. Thanks.